# xmlSerializer.Deserialize poorly formed XML

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, serialization, xmlserializer

I'm attempting to deserialize the XML (below)

I'm stuck due to the "non-standard" structure of the XML. Instead of the normal way to serialize a Products collection, ie: a  parent with many  child elements. They have many parent  elements each with a single  child element.

My issue is that due to this unusual array structure (I suspect due to a bug), I can't figure out how to set the attributes ie:[XMLArrayItem] so that I can extract meaningful data.

Note: The XML is an HTTPResponse from a public 3rd party. (So I can't get them to change it.)

Specifically: Instead of a < Products> parent with many < Product> elements.

The < betType> node has multiple < Products> parent elements each with a single < Product> child element.

You have total freedom to create whatever classes with whatever properties are needed. 
Clearly the solution needs BetType & Product classes. I've tried both with & without a Products class.

```
<rootnode>
:
  <bet_types>
    <bet_type id="105">
      <name>Exacta</name>
      <products>
        <product id="17">
            <name>STAB</name>
            <max_stake>10000</max_stake>
            <allow_multiple>0</allow_multiple>
            <allow_flexi>1</allow_flexi>
            <product_default>1</product_default>
        </product>
      </products>
      <products>
        <product id="25">
              <name>NSW</name>
              <max_stake>10000</max_stake>
              <allow_multiple>0</allow_multiple>
              <allow_flexi>1</allow_flexi>
         </product>
      </products>
    </bet_type>

    <bet_type id="107">
      <name>Quinella</name>
      <products>
        <product id="18">
            <name>STAB</name>
            <max_stake>10000</max_stake>
            <allow_multiple>0</allow_multiple>
            <allow_flexi>1</allow_flexi>
            <product_default>1</product_default>
        </product>
      </products>
      <products>
        <product id="26">
            <name>NSW</name>
            <max_stake>10000</max_stake>
            <allow_multiple>0</allow_multiple>
            <allow_flexi>1</allow_flexi>
        </product>
      </products>
    </bet_type>
:
</rootnode>
```

Ideally we could use the .Net C# xmlSerializer as I'm using it for all the other calls. And this sample is a small fragment nested deep in the HTTPResponse.

One possible alternative be to use XSLT to reformat it, but am hoping there is a way to do it with attributes. I think it is cleaner, & I'm unsure how I'd write the XSLT to do it.

Note: Alternatively if you can suggest a way to "not produce" a Node for the parent array & just create the node for each array item, that would help. As one of the approaches I've tried got really close. But I still had a "Products" node that was a parent to the multiple Products nodes that each contained a single Product node.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So why can't you use, XMlElement.SetAttribute? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1ah1zbw.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, create an XML schema for your XML document and run `xsd.exe` on it. You can then look at (or use) the generated code.

To get you started, here's an XML schema that matches the XML you posted above. Run `xsd.exe /c /f /n:Your.Namespace.Here FileName.xsd` to generate the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" >
  <xs:element name="rootnode">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="bet_types">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="bet_type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="products" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="product">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="max_stake" type="xs:int" />
                                <xs:element name="allow_multiple" type="xs:int" />
                                <xs:element name="allow_flexi" type="xs:int" />
                                <xs:element name="product_default" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                              <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required" />
                            </xs:complexType>                            
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Interesting that this worked. As I had used XSD initially to create schemas from the XML returned & then used it to create the classes I was using. It worked fine for most things but generated an incorrect clas for this so that I was only getting an Instance for the last item in the Products array. 
Possibly the /f flag did the magic. OR maybe it was a able to generate better classes from a much simpler schema. (ie: some obscure bug due to large complex schemas. OR maybe the large XML produced an inaccurate XSD. 

The lesson is: try breaking the complex schema into parts. Thanks

Comment: Sorry Micheal I'd like to Vote up your Answer, but I lost my work email & now have to start again with insufficient reputation to participate in anything.